# saslauthd on centos no authentication

Tags: centos, saslauthd

I want instal on centos 6.4 postfix with auth-smtp, i instal sasl

```
 ps -ef | grep pam
root      3148     1  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam
root      3150  3148  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam
root      3151  3148  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam
root      3152  3148  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam
root      3153  3148  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam
root      3237  1276  0 16:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep pam
```

but if it test

```
testsaslauthd -u user -p pass
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

in  /var/log/messages

```
auth failure: [user=mardon] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]


cat /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

why testsaslauthd not authenticate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `saslauthd` was configured to contact the PAM authentication framework, you have to specify an additional `-s smtp`:

```
$ testsaslauthd -u user -p pass -s smtp
```

Answer (score 1):

2016/03/31 Had a similar issue on my Fedora 15. By setting FLAGS=-d in /etc/init.d/saslauthd and restarting it, I found, by inspecting /var/log/messages that testsaslauthd uses the imap service by default. A little tidbit of information the author though he'd keep to himself :( On my system, too, saslauthd is configured, in /etc/sysconfig/saslauthd to use PAM. There was no /etc/pam.d/imap file on my system. After I copied /etc/pam.d/smtp to imap the "problem" was solved. While I was there, I made sure there was an /etc/pam.d/pop also.